# Binding properties to controls using reflection

Tags: c#, data-binding, reflection

I am trying to bind properties from object using reflection to textbox, object passed in is simple class with public primitive type properties and some code in getter/setter. But changing values in textbox doesn't reflect changes to instance of object, values never gets updated, what am I missing?

```
public object myObj;

public void setObject(ref object myObject)
{
    myObj = myObject;
}

var textbox = new Textbox();
...
textbox.DataBindings.Add("Text", myObj, myObj.GetType().GetProperties()[0].Name);
this.Controls.Add(textbox);
```

Comment: try passing in your real object, and binding to the property that way.
Then, if that works, revert to your way, but spread everything out, such that
`Type myType = myobj.GetType()` then `myproperties = myType.GetProperties()` etc to see if a step is failing...

Comment: @ImmortalBlue I tired both already but it doesn't work, spreading out doesn't really matter because I'am only after string - Name. Passing by reference seems more logical because I want to reflect changes to object that is somewhere outside this code.

Comment: the point I was trying to make is two fold. Firstly, by passing in your original type, and it doesn't work, you've shown that reflection isn't the problem. Ignoring that, secondly, by spreading out the calls, just for debug purposes you can step into that method and see which step isn't doing what you wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742863.aspx) please.

You need to have:

```
  Binding myBinding = new Binding("MyDataProperty"); //name of the property on the object which is used as binding source
  myBinding.Source = myObject;
  textbox.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, myBinding);
```

Comment: I implemented INotifyPropertyChanged although I don't think this mattered AFAIK INotifyPropertyChanged is for 2 way binding?, and restarted VS and things started to work. So either INotifyPropertyChanged helped or something got glitchy.

Comment: ah, the ancient 'restart vs' trick worked:) no, inpc is not required for data binding in the one way to source mode, i.e. if you type in a bound text box, the underlying object will be updated irrespective of inpc. however if the property changes from code and the obj does not implement inpc, the change will not be shown in the ui.